# I want to get data from a table in Sql and assign them to a List<...> in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get data from a table in Sql and assign them to a List<...> in C#. For example, I have a Sql table containing employee information, then I will take the data of that table and convert it into elements of a List

Comment: This is too broad for Stackoverflow since that question encloses other ones. I suggest to find a tutorial in Google that makes something similar to what you want to achieve. Then you could ask a specific question if you get stuck at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SqlDataReader` to read all employees from SQL and then add them in employees list. Here is a sample code.

```
public List<Employee> FetchEmployeesFromSqlDB(){

 //Create an employees list
 List<Employee> employeesFromDb = new List<Employee>();   

// Replace the connection string with your connection string
string connectionString = "Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;User ID=YourUsername;Password=YourPassword";

// Replace with your actual table name
string query = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Get all attributes that you need
                int employeeId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("EmployeeId"));
                string firstName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName"));
                string lastName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("LastName"));

                // Create an Employee object
                Employee employee = new Employee(employeeId, firstName, lastName);

                // Add employees to the list
                employeesFromDb.Add(employee);
            }
        }
    }
}

return employeesFromDb; }
```

Comment: oh, Thank you so much! And Can you say about  get data of a list and assign them to an SQL table?

Comment: Well , you can use `SqlCommand ` with your specific query and connection string to insert data into SQL. You can post a new and can get a complete answer there as this question is only relevant to fetching data.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a type that looks similar to your data:

```cs
public class Employee {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    // ... Etc, columns
}
```

2. Use Dapper or EF; for a Dapper example:

```cs
var list = connection.Query<Employee>(
    "select * from Employees").AsList();
```

Note that adding parameters to the query is trivial with both Dapper and EF; refer to the relevant docs.